# mobile version site mobile number always White color

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-website, mobile-devices

I created `mobile version` site for my `Wordpress website`. I created **m.mysite.com**. When I see m.mysite.com, mobile number showing what color(#000) I gave. But in mobile device, It's shows always `White Color`.

Code is,

```
<div class="header_number">
    281-407-6199
</div>
```

CSS is,

```
.header_number{
    background: url(images/bg_3.png);
    background-color:#919191;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:26px;
    color:#813010 !important;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
}
header_number a{
    color:#813010 !important;
}
```

I need to make it as same color in mobile device also. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
header_number a{
```

to

```
.header_number a{
```

You are missing DOT(.) in it.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your style.

```
.header_number a{...}
```

Add DOT to class name.